# Amazon encryption with S3

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3

I want to upload files to Aamazon S3 service. I also want these files to be available to users to share but only with a link that no one else can guess. Something that Trello app does. Example of a link to a test file is

https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/5215040bd3afdaa3500010db/525c8cf285f31702580008c0/39b48c4a06a309b2367b5e9c9bfe3593/test.txt

Is this being accomplished using [Amazon S3 Encryption?](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryption.html)

Comment: I don't see why you'd need encryption just to get unguessable urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side encryption, as described in the link you posted means that the file that's stored on S3 will be encrypted before being sent to S3. When someone accesses the file, they won't be able to decrypt it without the correct keys and S3 will not have access to those keys.

To control access to files for a certain group of users, you can either use unique, non-guessable URLs like the Trello example you posted, or use S3 signed URLs as described here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth